# Why does Pandas Multi-index slicing return results from outside of the slice?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataset with a multi index, lets say on Group (string) and Date(datetime64). When attempting to slice this dataset using

```
.xs(slice(startDate,endDate),level='Date',drop_level = False)
```

I thought that I would get back the dataset with the same groups, but no dates outside of the start/end range.

Instead I have some groups sliced by the start/end range, some with missing entries, and others seemingly not sliced at all.

For example:

```
d={'group':['a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t'],
'date':[np.datetime64('2005-02-25'),np.datetime64('2005-02-25'),np.datetime64('2005-02-27'),
np.datetime64('2005-02-25'),np.datetime64('2005-02-26'),np.datetime64('2005-02-27'),np.datetime64('2005-02-26'),
np.datetime64('2005-01-25'),np.datetime64('2005-02-25'),np.datetime64('2005-03-27'),np.datetime64('2005-04-25'),np.datetime64('2005-05-26'),np.datetime64('2005-06-27'),np.datetime64('2005-07-26'),
np.datetime64('2005-01-25'),np.datetime64('2005-02-25'),np.datetime64('2005-03-27'),np.datetime64('2005-04-25'),np.datetime64('2005-05-26'),np.datetime64('2005-06-27'),np.datetime64('2005-07-26'),
np.datetime64('2005-02-25'),np.datetime64('2005-02-25'),np.datetime64('2005-02-27'),np.datetime64('2005-02-25'),np.datetime64('2005-02-26'),np.datetime64('2005-02-27'),np.datetime64('2005-02-26')],
'data':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}

df = pandas.DataFrame(d)
aggregate = df.groupby(('group','date')).sum()
aggregate
```

will produce

```
                  data
group date            
a     2005-02-25     3
      2005-02-27     3
b     2005-02-25     4
      2005-02-26    12
      2005-02-27     6
c     2005-01-25     1
      2005-02-25     2
      2005-03-27     3
      2005-04-25     4
      2005-05-26     5
      2005-06-27     6
      2005-07-26     7
t     2005-01-25     1
      2005-02-25     9
      2005-02-26    12
      2005-02-27     9
      2005-03-27     3
      2005-04-25     4
      2005-05-26     5
      2005-06-27     6
      2005-07-26     7
```

and

```
startDate = np.datetime64('2005-02-25')
endDate = np.datetime64('2005-02-26')
aggregate.xs(slice(startDate,endDate),level='date',drop_level = False)
```

might produce

```
                  data
group date            
a     2005-02-25     3
b     2005-02-25     4
      2005-02-26    12
c     2005-01-25     1
      2005-02-25     2
t     2005-01-25     1
      2005-02-25     9
      2005-02-26    12
      2005-02-27     9
      2005-03-27     3
      2005-04-25     4
      2005-05-26     5
      2005-06-27     6
      2005-07-26     7
```

(before anyone runs that code snippet, it actually works exactly as expected, the example output is illustrative)

I feel like I must be making a blindingly obvious mistake.
Can anyone explain why and tell me where I'm using the multi index slicing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the behavior that you're describing, along with sample input/output.

Comment: Sadly it's using a large chunk of protected data, and I haven't been able to reproduce the exact issue I'm having with sample inputs. I can post example code to show the problem I'm trying to solve, but it doesn't reproduce the problem on it's own.

Comment: @root: Example added, though as I note it doesn't reproduce the issue, just illustrates it.